# Dozer NullPointerException on deep-mapping with custom getter

Tags: dozer

Im getting this exception:

```
Field mapping error -->
MapId: null
Type: null
Source parent class: com.ParentObject
Source field name: field1
Source field type: class com.OnOff1BitEnum
Source field value: OFF
Dest parent class: com.SubParent
Dest field name: subParent.field2
Dest field type: java.lang.Boolean java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.dozer.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:270)
at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.getDeepSrcFieldValue(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:116)
at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.getPropertyValue(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:69)
at org.dozer.fieldmap.FieldMap.getDestValue(FieldMap.java:141)
```

This is the mapping field:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.ParentObject</class-a>
    <class-b>com.SubParent</class-b>

    <field custom-converter="com.OnOffEnumToBooleanConverter">
        <a>field1</a> 
        <b get-method="isField2">subParent.field2</b> 
    </field>
</mapping>
```

The version of dozer i am using is 5.4.0

UPDATE:
Added the converter code to this post.
When i put a break point here this is not being reached

```
public class OnOffEnumToBooleanConverter implements org.dozer.CustomConverter {
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Object convert(Object dest, Object src, Class<?> destClass, Class<?> srcClass) {
    if (src == null) {
        return null;
    }
            if (src instanceof com.OnOff1BitEnum) {
        boolean canonicalObject;
        if ((com.OnOff1BitEnum) src == com.OnOff1BitEnum.ON) {
            canonicalObject = true;
        } else if ((com.OnOff1BitEnum) src == com.OnOff1BitEnum.OFF) {
            canonicalObject = false;
        } else { // Unreachable Code To Test
            throw new MappingException("Converter " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " used incorrectly.  Arguments passed in were: "
                    + dest + " and " + src);
        }
        return canonicalObject;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Publish source code of your converter com.OnOffEnumToBooleanConverter

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it happens because you are missing "set configuration", try specifying it explicitly and see if that solves it or a different error happens, e.g.

```
<field custom-converter="com.OnOffEnumToBooleanConverter">
        <a>field1</a> 
        <b get-method="isField2" set-method="field2">subParent.field2</b> 
</field>
```

UPDATE:

I had to properly format your java code to be able to read...here is the problem you have "if and else" for a boolean value...there is no 3rd condition...just carefully look at it:

```
if (src instanceof com.OnOff1BitEnum)
{
  boolean canonicalObject;
  if ((com.OnOff1BitEnum) src == com.OnOff1BitEnum.ON)
  {
    canonicalObject = true;
  }
  else
  {
    if ((com.OnOff1BitEnum) src == com.OnOff1BitEnum.OFF)
    {
      canonicalObject = false;
    }
    else
    { // Unreachable Code To Test
      throw new MappingException("Converter " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName()
          + " used incorrectly.  Arguments passed in were: " + dest + " and " + src);
    }
  }
  return canonicalObject;
}
```

That's the evil of "if else construct" that has no brackets in your original code. 
Also your "convert" method returns Object...so your "`boolean canonicalObject`" has to be "**Boolean** canonicalObject" not primitive type.

Should be:

```
@Override
public Object convert(Object dest, Object src, Class<?> destClass, Class<?> srcClass) 
{    
    if (src instanceof com.OnOff1BitEnum)
    {
      if ((com.OnOff1BitEnum) src == com.OnOff1BitEnum.ON)
      {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
      }
      else
      {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I got the same error after changing the converter to what you suggested